# MediaWiki: Two problems (LimitInternalRecursion & app.php not found) with new installation

Tags: php, apache, config, mediawiki

On my server I create a subfolder calls "wiki" and a subdomain "wiki.mydomain.com" which point to the subfolder. I download the new 1.27.1 wiki from this site and install it. Now I have two big problems:

1. Problem: If I upload files I select my file and press the upload button. Now the site refresh but the file is not uploaded. I get the same uploaded mask. If I select the file a second time the upload works.
2. Problem: Sometimes if I want to save a article / site I get this error message:

   > Sorry! We could not process your edit due to a loss of session data. Please try again. If it still doesn't work, try logging out and logging back in.

Now I look into my error logs and get these errors:

> [Mon Sep 05 23:26:43 2016] [-:error] [pid 31729] [client
>   127.0.0.1:47076] [host wiki.lythoria.de] script '/is/htdocs/wp12677946_S31BDZISFX/www/wiki/images/app.php' not found
>   or unable to stat
>   [Mon Sep 05 23:28:12 2016] [core:error] [pid 6346] [client
>   127.0.0.1:48430] [host wiki.lythoria.de] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.
>   Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use
>   'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
>   [Mon Sep 05 23:28:12 2016] [core:error] [pid 6346] [client
>   127.0.0.1:48430] [host wiki.lythoria.de] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.
>   Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use
>   'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
>   [Mon Sep 05 23:28:56 2016] [-:error] [pid 6780] [client
>   127.0.0.1:49060] [host wiki.lythoria.de] script '/is/htdocs/wp12677946_S31BDZISFX/www/wiki/images/app.php' not found
>   or unable to stat
>   [Mon Sep 05 23:29:36 2016] [core:error] [pid 7402] [client
>   127.0.0.1:49684] [host www.wiki.lythoria.de] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration
>   error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if
>   necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
>   [Mon Sep 05 23:29:36 2016] [core:error] [pid 7402] [client
>   127.0.0.1:49684] [host www.wiki.lythoria.de] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration
>   error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if
>   necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
>   [Mon Sep 05 23:29:36 2016] [-:error] [pid 7403] [client
>   127.0.0.1:49686] [host www.wiki.lythoria.de] script '/is/htdocs/wp12677946_S31BDZISFX/www/wiki/images/app.php' not found
>   or unable to stat
>   [Mon Sep 05 23:29:45 2016] [core:error] [pid 7505] [client
>   127.0.0.1:49770] [host wiki.lythoria.de] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.
>   Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use
>   'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

I don't know why. The problems don't always occur, but very often. Can someone help me with these problems?

Additional information:

- MediaWiki 1.27.1
- PHP 5.6.25-he.0 (apache2handler)
- MYSQL 5.6.31-77.0-log
- ICU 52.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app.php is not part of the MediaWiki code, so this is not a MediaWiki issue. You probably followed some unsupported installation method and configured the cache and file backend incorrectly.

I can only suggest to [follow the installation guide](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Installation_guide) and [the advice you  got on debugging](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Tb1gdhnrj7yjegpr) from Cienca al Poder.